# how to subtract two dates in vb. with the if condition

Tags: vb.net

hi I have some problem in subtraction the dates if they satisfied the condition using the if then statment would you please help me find it . fist of all the user will enter a date and then add 350 days so we have two dates. then subtract it and multiplay it and add some identified values.

```
  Private Sub CalculateButton_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles CalculateButton.Click
        Dim intdep_number As Integer​
        Dim dtmexpierdate As Date​
        Dim A As Integer​
        Dim B As Integer​
        Dim C As Integer​
        Dim days As Integer​
        Dim dtmIssuedate As Date​
        Dim intThirdA As Integer = 7310​
        Dim intFirstA As Integer = (3650 / 3)​
        Dim intSecondA As Integer = 3650​
        intdep_number = NumberofDependentTextBox.Text​
        dtmexpierdate = DateTimePicker2.Value​
        days = Val(365)​
        Label1.Text = ("The date sum is:" & " " & DateAdd(DateInterval.Day, days, dtmexpierdate))​
​
        If (dtmexpierdate <= Date.FromOADate(30 / 6 / 2019)) Then​
            A = DateDiff(DateInterval.Day, dtmexpierdate.Date, Date.FromOADate(30 / 6 / 2018).Date) + intFirstA * (20 / 3)​
​
        ElseIf (dtmexpierdate.ToString <= Date.FromOADate(30 / 6 / 2020)) Then​
            A = DateDiff(DateInterval.Day, dtmexpierdate.Date, Date.FromOADate(30 / 6 / 2019).ToString) + intSecondA * (10)​
​
        Else​
            A = DateDiff(DateInterval.Day, dtmexpierdate.Date, Date.FromOADate(30 / 6 / 2020).ToString) + intThirdA * (13.3)​
        End If​
​
        If (dtmIssuedate <= Date.FromOADate(30 / 6 / 2019)) Then​
            B = DateDiff(DateInterval.Day, dtmIssuedate.Date, Date.FromOADate(30 / 6 / 2018).ToString) + intFirstA * (20 / 3)​
​
        ElseIf (dtmIssuedate.ToString <= Date.FromOADate(30 / 6 / 2020)) Then​
            B = DateDiff(DateInterval.Day, dtmIssuedate.Date, Date.FromOADate(30 / 6 / 2019).ToString) + intSecondA * (10)​
​
        Else​
            B = DateDiff(DateInterval.Day, dtmIssuedate.Date, Date.FromOADate(30 / 6 / 2020).ToString) + intThirdA * (13.3)​
        End If​
        C = (B - A) - 1​
        Label2.Text = C * intdep_number​
    End Sub
```

Comment: `Option Strict On` **!** and fix the errors.  Then learn what `Date.FromOADate` is intended for (it is not for how you are using it).

Comment: `days = Val(365)`  seriously?

Comment: Date.FromOADate function receives a double as parameter. So you are sending to the function, in the first case: 30 / 6 / 2019 = 0,0024764735017335 (Note the / is used to divide). Is this what you want? (To send 0,0024764735017335 as a parameter to the function? I think no...)

Comment: What @Jortx mentioned I already said on [an earlier question of yours](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53260496/how-can-i-write-this-date-and-value-in-correct-way-and-to-remove-the-error#comment93418701_53260496). How come you haven't taken my advice and fixed it, or at least replied explaining why you cannot use it? Despite popular belief, as this situation has shown, re-asking the same question isn't going to get you a different answer.

Comment: DateTime.Subtract() ?